# How to preserve space in HTML select option list?

Tags: php, html, html-select

```
<select name='test'>
<option value='north' india>north india</option>
<option value='goa'>goa</option>
</select>
```

If I select "north india" in the list PHP echos only "north". Why is that?

This HTML is generated by the PHP code below:

```
    $cond_city= "WHERE state=? GROUP BY cityName ORDER BY cityName ASC";
    $data_city= array($state);
    $select_city=$this->select_rows(TABLEPREFIX.'region','*',$cond_city,$data_city);    
          while($arr_city=$select_city->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
echo '<option value='.$arr_city['cityName'].'>'.$arr_city['cityName'].'</option>';  
}
```

Comment: Looking at the syntax highlighting in the question itself show the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `value` is equal to `'north'` because you misplaced your quote:

```
<option value='north' india>north india</option>
```

You need this instead:

```
<option value='north india'>north india</option>
```

To get this result, you will need to add quotes in your PHP code, like this:

```
<?php

$cond = "WHERE state=? GROUP BY cityName ORDER BY cityName ASC";
$data = array($state);
$select=$this->select_rows(TABLEPREFIX.'region','*',$cond_city,$data_city); 
while ($arr_city=$select_city->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option value="'.$arr_cit.' '.$sel_cnt.' >'.$arr_city['cityName']."'</option>'; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have set option's value as 'north'. If you want 'north india'as whole then replace below code.

```
<select name='test'>
    <option value='north india'>north india</option>
    <option value='goa'>goa</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's happening because when you are submitting your data, you have value for the name of the input (`select` in your case). To get the desired value you should indicate it in the `value` attribute of the select.

```
<select name='test'>
    <option value="north india">North India</option>
</select>
```